# Transform the system of trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

How to extract $\ell$ and $L$ from the following system of equations:
$$\alpha=\arctan {R_E \cos \ell \sin L \over R_0 + R_E(1 - \cos \ell \cos L) }$$
$$\beta=\arctan {R_E \sin \ell \cos \alpha \over R_0 + R_E(1 - \cos \ell \cos L) } $$

Comment: Do you mean to have $\alpha$ in the right hand side of your second equation, or is it supposed to be $L$?

Comment: It is $\alpha$.

Comment: The reason why you saw $\alpha=\arctan {R_E \cos l \sin L \over R_0 + R_E(1 - \cos l \cos L) }$ instead of $\displaystyle \alpha=\arctan {R_E \cos l \sin L \over R_0 + R_E(1 - \cos l \cos L) }$ is that you didn't follow standard MathJax usages.  See my edit to the question for details. $\qquad$